# Problem(NOT error) sending and receive-ing data, to `Isolate.spawn`

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to send, `Uint8List` to `Isolate.spawn`, which only accepts a single argument, `message`, so I can, send either the `byte_array`, or the `SendPort`, but not both; In below given code I sent the `byte_array` as `message`, and tried to use `Isolate.current.controlPort` inside the `entryPoint`, to `send` a `message` to `receive_port.listen`, but message is not `receive`ed(printed) .

Code:

```dart
import "dart:isolate";
import "dart:typed_data";

Future<void> main() async {
  final ReceivePort receive_port = ReceivePort();

  final Uint8List bytes = Uint8List(0);
  print("out.bytes.length: ${bytes.length}");

  final Isolate isolate = await Isolate.spawn(
    (final Uint8List bytes) {
      print("in.bytes.length: ${bytes.length}");

      final SendPort send_port = Isolate.current.controlPort //
        ..send(0);
    },
    bytes,
  );

  await receive_port
      .listen(
        (final Object? res) => //
            print("out.receive_port.listen.result: $res"),
        onError: (
          final Object err,
          final StackTrace trace,
        ) => //
            print("out.receive_port.onError"
                "..err:\"$err\""
                "..trace:\"$trace\""),
        onDone: () => //
            print("out.receive_port.onDone"),
      )
      .asFuture<void>();

  print("out: KILL-ing isolate NOW");
  isolate.kill();
}
```

I also tried `<Object>[byte_array, receive_port]`, `List<Object>.filled(2, ...)`, and `(byte_array, receive_port)`(record).

I searched google, including SO, but not found solution,

This question is tagged with `flutter`, because many flutter devs don't even know about the existence of dart lang. Yes you read that right.

thanks

Comment: "I can, send either the `byte_array`, or the `SendPort`, but not both". Why not create a class to hold both values and pass that in? Or if you are on dart 3, you can use a record to hold both values and pass that in.

Comment: > "I also tried <Object>[byte_array, receive_port], List<Object>.filled(2, ...), and (byte_array, receive_port)(record)"